# Google Map embedded in website loading Google page rather than the map

Tags: google-maps

I have this website - http://www.gyroontario.ca/contact/ which has a Google Map embedded within it. This has worked fine for many years but all of a sudden the embedded map is trying to load the Google Maps page instead of just embedding the map.

If you load the link, it initially loads the map correctly but then all of a sudden it loads the maps page with all the Google main menu and sidebar.

Is there something that has been changed by Google because we haven't touched the site for a long time. How can I fix this?

This is an image of what it's embedding:

[image]

This is the code I've embedded:

```
<iframe width="525" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=50+Skyway+Drive,+Guelph,+ON+N1H+6H8&amp;aq=&amp;sll=51.502241,-3.19941&amp;sspn=0.260515,0.380058&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Skyway+Dr,+Guelph,+Wellington+County,+Ontario+N1H+6H8,+Canada&amp;t=m&amp;ll=43.565031,-80.19762&amp;spn=0.021767,0.045061&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

---

This is how I'm getting the code, just a simple google embed code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up your page (line ~85):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        frames[i].src += "?wmode=transparent";
    }
}
```

is responsible the loading of the complete google maps page.
You can easily check this by creating an empty page with the google maps-`iframe` element only (will work)
and than adding the `window.onload` from your page.

BTW: contact/tooltip.css is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The `iframe` contains the URL

```
https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=50+Skyway+Drive,Guelph,+ON+N1H+6H8&aq=&sll=43.361335,-79.923517&sspn=1.217084,1.520233&gl=uk&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Skyway+Dr,+Guelph,+Wellington+County,+Ontario+N1H+6H8,+Canada&t=m&ll=43.565031,-80.19762&spn=0.012438,0.023861&z=14&iwloc=A&output=embed?wmode=transparent
```

which directly refers the UK's Google maps.  I'm not sure how it worked initially and later changed.

But you can fix by using the [**Google maps v3**]  (used now a days)(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).

Remove `iframe` and try doing the below and use **Google Maps JavaScript API v3**.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.565529, -80.197645);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     //=====Initialise Default Marker    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'marker'
     //=====You can even customize the icons here
    });

     //=====Initialise InfoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<B>Skyway Dr</B>"
  });

   //=====Eventlistener for InfoWindow
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have created a [**simple fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2625/) for your reference.

Hope you got some idea.

---

**Updates:**

I think the problem is with `wmode=transparent` in the `iframe` URL.  When I remove it is working.  Check [**fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/fecdy/) and [**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fecdy/1/)

See difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: It's just a simple embedded map, there's no geocoding etc. The code in the question is just taken from the code Google give you to embed the map.

Comment: @Rob why you need Geocoding for display a static place.  Here  `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.565529, -80.197645);` is the geocoded part of your location.

Comment: See updated question, I've never needed to do that before, in the screenshot I've added it shows how I've always added the map.

Comment: @Rob **FYI:** I haven't copied google's sample code.  This is the procedure that everyone has to follow.  It took around 20 mins to prepare a working fiddle for you.

Comment: @user1671639 Ok great, thanks. It didn't actually have `wmode=transparent` in the original code, I tried adding it as well just in case but still no luck.