# How to lazy load Google Maps on click Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The website which I am building for a company

The company which I am developing a website has 3 locations and I show embedded maps on the website. However, since it takes a lot of time to load the maps, I want the maps to be loaded after I hover a menu item.

Let me show you the [WEBSITE](http://www.carantina.com).

On this website on the top navbar there is a box called 'ILETISIM'.

So normally when I load my website the 3 maps are loaded automatically in order to show maps. It doesn't matter if I hover on 'ILETISIM' item.

What I want is I want them to start loading after I hover on ILETİSİM. There should be something like lazy load. By this way the loading time will decrease.

[image]

```
<li class="dropdown full-width"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">İLETİŞİM<b class="icon-angle-down"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu span12 iletisim" style="width: 980px; left: -493px;">
             <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="span12">
                     <div class="span4">
                         <div class="span12">
                             <div class="well well-small">GENEL MÜDÜRLÜK VE FABRİKA</div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="span6">
                             <ul class="unstyled">
                                 <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                                     Email
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="divider"></li>
                                 <a href="#">sales@goxu.com.tr</a>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                         <div class="span6">
                             <ul class="unstyled">
                                 <li><i class="icon-user"></i>
                                     Telefon
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="divider"></li>
                                 <p>+90 216 466 89 89</p>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                         <div class="span12">
                             <ul class="unstyled">
                                 <li><i class="icon-home"></i>
                                     Adres
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="divider"></li>
                                 <p>Dudullu Organize Sanayi Bölgesi
                                     3.Cad. No:14 Ümraniye 34775 İSTANBUL</p>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                         <div class="span12">
                             <ul class="unstyled">
                                 <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
                                     Harita
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="divider"></li>
                                 <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                            <div class="Flexible-container">
                                <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=de&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Bern&amp;aq=&amp;sll=46.813187,8.22421&amp;sspn=3.379772,8.453979&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Bern&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;ll=46.947922,7.444608&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="well well-small">GENEL MÜDÜRLÜK VE FABRİKA</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                                Email
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <a href="#">sales@goxu.com.tr</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-user"></i>
                                Telefon
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <p>+90 216 466 89 89</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-home"></i>
                                Adres
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <p>Dudullu Organize Sanayi Bölgesi
                                3.Cad. No:14 Ümraniye 34775 İSTANBUL</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
                                Harita
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                            <div class="Flexible-container">
                                <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=de&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Bern&amp;aq=&amp;sll=46.813187,8.22421&amp;sspn=3.379772,8.453979&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Bern&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;ll=46.947922,7.444608&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="well well-small">GENEL MÜDÜRLÜK VE FABRİKA</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                                Email
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <a href="#">sales@goxu.com.tr</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-user"></i>
                                Telefon
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <p>+90 216 466 89 89</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-home"></i>
                                Adres
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <p>Dudullu Organize Sanayi Bölgesi
                                3.Cad. No:14 Ümraniye 34775 İSTANBUL</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
                                Harita
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                            <div class="Flexible-container">
                                <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=de&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Bern&amp;aq=&amp;sll=46.813187,8.22421&amp;sspn=3.379772,8.453979&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Bern&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;ll=46.947922,7.444608&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div></ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First thing***, you're not using **`Google maps API`**, it is called as [**`iframe Google maps`**](http://designshack.net/articles/html/embedding-google-maps-into-a-web-page-a-beginners-guide/) embedding.

They both are enirely different.

So you need to play something like below to do some lazy loading

```
 $('.someClass').hover(){
        var src1 = "your iframe1 url", 
        src2 = "your iframe2 url", 
        src3 = "your iframe3 url"; 
        $('#iFrame1').show().prop('src', src1);     //Have IDs for your iframes
        $('#iFrame2').show().prop('src', src2);     //because each has its src
        $('#iFrame3').show().prop('src', src3);     
    },function(){
       $('iFrame1').hide();    //You can even remove the src instead of hiding
       $('iFrame2').hide();      
       $('iFrame3').hide();    //Also you can even have it in setTimeout()
    });
```

Hope you got some idea.

**Updates:**

If you want to change to Google Maps API, check [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616832/1671639).

Comment: So how could I have done this with Google Maps Api ? It looks like it is the rightway.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a reference.  Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach a handler to the `mouseover` event of your link/button, and have that function initialize your Google map..

```
$('#btn1').mouseover(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

You probably want to give your 'ILETISIM' link a unique id attribute, or you can change the selector above to `$('[data-toggle=dropdown]')` to have the mouseover function attached to all of your menu links.

Working demo: http://bootply.com/68978

Comment: But this is not a lazy load. What I mean by lazy load is when the page is loaded the embedded google map will not be initialized. It will be initialized when I click on it. Please check I explained this in simpler way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787006/how-to-convert-static-google-maps-to-dynamic-google-maps-onclick-static-maps

Answer (score 0):

Further to Skelly's answer.

You can simply using an image replacement technique to achieve your requirements.

see the sample at - http://bootply.com/68986

```
$('#staticimg').click(function(){
    initialize();
    $('#staticimg').remove();
});
```

This simply works by initialising the google map on the div and removing the static image.  Alter as needed.

You can also change the event handler to be `hover`.

Comment: The problem in here is; the google maps is still pre-loading. What I want is I want to be loaded ( all data ) when I click on the image. My goal is to decrease loading times.

Comment: I am not sure what you are using to measure the pre-loading.  Looking at the raw get for firefox using the above code and Skelly's - There is not loading from google until the initalise event is triggered.  That is the purpose of that function call to inialise and load google maps bits.

Comment: If you mean to prevent the google maps api itself from preloading, then you can embed it's loading call within the click function.