# How to convert Static Google Maps to Dynamic Google Maps onclick Static maps?

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

This is a static Google Maps. [Click this link to view](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false) You can also view from [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/UQLss/)

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

What I want is when I click on this image on my website, it automatically turns from static to dynamic Google Maps.

By this way, the map will not be loaded automatically and loading time will be reduced.

Answer (score -1):

I actually wrote a jQuery plugin quite a while back that converts a static Google Map to a dynamic one.

I can't guarantee that every parameter works (like marker styling for example), but it might help.

http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/static-to-dynamic-gm/

I actually found this question while Googling for some official way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @powerbuoy this link is broken.

Comment: Sorry Drake, that was five years ago... Don't think I even put the code on Github.