# How can I create a google map with 2000+ points without loading any data on the client side

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

Edit: To be clear when i say sample code I mean a small demonstration of the concept not fully functional JS and HTML as some might assume. I am unsure how to create 2k markers and load them into the map other than having `var marker1`, `var marker2`, `var marker3`, etc.  Currently I have this small script to load the map with one marker.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function InitializeMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 4,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35),
            map: map
        });
    };
    window.onload = InitializeMap;

</script>
```

When I say server side, I mean that I want to create the map/create the markers on a server and then load the map from this server on the client side. I don't want to have 2,000 marker objects, 2,000 sets of coordinates and information, or 2,000 of anything loaded on the client side.

End of Edits

I am new to the Google maps API and javascript so please bear with me if my question seems trivial.

I want to create a google map using the maps api with about 2K+ markers. I already have the latitudes and longitudes for the locations. What I would like to do if it is possible with the API is create the map server side (upload all the points and set all the settings) and then load the map on the client side using a url.

Is this doable with the Google maps API?

<strike>Could anyone show me some sample javascript that creates the map and some sample html that uploads and displays the map?</strike>

Comment: 2k+ with static lat/lng is not a trivial one.  here is a [simple way to create a map, marker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17616832/1671639).The only part I don't understand is: what does server side means in you're question?

Comment: The Google Maps API is client side.. so you can't do it server side.

Comment: Investigate loading your markers from a KML file (using [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)) or putting the data in a FusionTable and using a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

Comment: @geocodezip your comment was exactly the answer I was looking for. I can load the information into an external source and reference them client side using a Fusion Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps API supports two mechanisms for loading markers from external data source (they are rendered on tiles by google's server, but the raw data isn't loaded to the client):

1. [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) - data from KML files on public servers
2. [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) - data from FusionTable