# Javascript variables outside of script tag and google maps integration

Tags: javascript, google-maps

so this is probably a noobish question, but i'm trying to have the user input a latitude and longitude and then use these values to pull up the location on google street view. I can get the google street view up on my website but I can't get this to work as planned.

```
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
 latittude=prompt("Please enter a latitude");
 longitude = prompt("please enter your longitude");

}
</script>
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=latittude,longitude&heading=235&sensor=false">
```

However, i'm not getting this to load properly and the map comes up first but instead I want the prompt to show up and then load the image based on the latitude and longitude, how can I do this? instead it just says it cannot display the image because latittude and logitude are uninitialized.

Comment: use var keyword infront of latitude and longitude , you haven't declared it

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass variable from script tag to html unless it is not done by event handler.  Instead you can do like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var x,
        latittude = prompt("Please enter a latitude");
        longitude = prompt("please enter your longitude");
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location='+ latittude + ',' + longitude + '&heading=235&sensor=false';
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);
}
```

If you're going to prompt multiple times then *you can change the src of image dynamically similar like the above code.*

If you're interested in *Google maps APIv3* then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616832/1671639).

Comment: Hi thanks for the information I was unaware of that; still can't get the image to load with this. Now nothing is appearing instead of a map saying the location cannot be found.